# One list item at a time

Tags: angularjs

I am a newbie to angular and i need to hide all list elements and display each list element on clicking next button.

I would also appreciate if someone could guide me through the documentation that explains the available commands like in jquery.

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you suppose to see one element-at-a-time or is it like "show more" where you load more elements?

Comment: One element at one time. I have already coded it in jquery but the client wants it in angularjs. Similar to this http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenForm/

Comment: Sounds like you just want to do paging. So instead of showing 10 at a time, you just want to show one at a time. This would work for any sized collection from 1 to X. Check out how to page using AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to do this. The best is probably by doing something with ng-repeat and storing the model of the list items in an array, but you could also do it in a less generic way like this, with a variable holding the item to be displayed and a button to increase the value. Of course you need to add some boundary checking.

```
<ul>
<li ng-show="showItem == 0">Item 1</li>
<li ng-show="showItem == 1">Item 2</li>
<li ng-show="showItem == 2">Item 3</li>
<li ng-show="showItem == 3">Item 4</li>
</ul>
<button ng-click="nextItem()">
```

In controller:

```
$scope.showItem = 0;
$scope.nextItem = new function() {
  $scope.showItem += 1
};
```

Comment: I got your point. But the concept is different that the html coder doesnt want to keep a track of showItem. Like in jquery, i collected/ showed first list item and hide the rest. And on click of next button i sliced the list items and went through.

Comment: Here we got no idea on the end of the list item. If someone could guide me to take the count of the list item it would be preferrable.  like $('ul li').each(function(){ elementCount++ });

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't want to keep track of showItem"?

Comment: He might add or remove some list items and the showItem count will also change accordingly.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene, I don't understand who "He" is. You need to be very precise about your constraints, so please edit your original question to that effect

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene, I agree with New Dev. Also, you should probably stop thinking about how it is done in jQuery. Using AngularJS requires a different way of thinking than jQuery, and if you're just going to try to do things the jQuery way, you should just use jQuery!

Comment: I apologise. I meant the way, in future, if the client or 3rd party developer other than me needs to add or delete any new list items he might not touch the backend coding.I am looking for a support on how to calculate the count of list items under ul tag.

Comment: Angular is not a backend technology, so I'm not sure how that would work. I think you have to let go of the idea that you could have people editing the html without understanding the Angular behind it, because in Angular, your html is your view and it's entangled with your controllers. It would make more sense to maintain your list of items in the controller than in the html.